# Datagridview filters in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, filter, datagridview

I'm trying to filter a datagridview containing flights, by chosing a period of time, a route or a budget.

The code seems to work fine for the route (RotaID) but not for the dates (DataHoraPartida) nor the budget (PrecoBase).

This is the code

```
Public Class FormProcurarViagem
    Private ListaViagens As New Viagens
    Private ListaRotas As New Rotas

    Private DataSetTemp As New DataSet()

    Private DataSource2Grid As New BindingSource()


    Public Event EnviaDadosViagem(ByVal NovaReservaViagem As ReservaViagem)

        Private Sub FormReservas_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ListaViagens = LerXML_Viagens()
        Me.ViagensBindingSource.DataSource = ListaViagens

        FillGrid()


        ListaRotas = LerXML_Rotas()

        With ComboBox1
            .DisplayMember = "RotaID"
            .ValueMember = "RotaID"
            .DataSource = ListaRotas
            .DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", ViagensBindingSource, "RotaID", DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
        End With

        With ComboBox2
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim j As Integer

            For j = 0 To 10
                i = i + 50
                ComboBox2.Items.Add(i)
            Next j


        End With

        DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
        DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
        DateTimePicker2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
        DateTimePicker2.CustomFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"

    End Sub

    Private Sub FillGrid()

          DataSetTemp.ReadXml("Viagens.xml")


        Dim tables As DataTableCollection = DataSetTemp.Tables

        Dim view1 As New DataView(tables(0))

        ViagensDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = True

        Me.Controls.Add(ViagensDataGridView)



        ' Create a BindingSource and set its DataSource property to the DataView.

        DataSource2Grid.DataSource = view1


        ' Set the data source for the DataGridView.

        ViagensDataGridView.DataSource = DataSource2Grid

    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        DataSource2Grid.Filter = String.Format("DataHoraPartida >= '{0:yyyy/MM/dd}' And DataHoraPartida <= '{1:yyyy/MM/dd}'", DateTimePicker1.Value.Date, DateTimePicker2.Value.Date)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        DataSource2Grid.Filter = "PrecoBase <=" & Me.ComboBox2.Text
    End Sub


    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted

        DataSource2Grid.Filter = "RotaID like '%" & Me.ComboBox1.Text & "%'"
    End Sub


End Class
```

In the data source the date format is yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm and the PrecoBase format is double, I don't know if that is what is causing the problem.

Comment: Firstly, creating a `DataView` yourself is almost certainly pointless. Every `DataTable` already has a `DataView` associated with it that you can access via its `DefaultView` property. When you bind a `DataTable`, it is actually its `DefaultView` that the data comes from. That's because `DataTable` implements `IListSource` and its `GetList` method returns its `DefaultView`. Unless you want multiple views of the same table, just bind the `DataTable` directly to your `BindingSource`.

Comment: Secondly, what does this mean: *"In the data source the date format is yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"*? Format is only relevant when talking about text. Please tell me that your `DataTable` doesn't contain `Strings` to represent dates. Dates should be stored as `DateTime` values in .NET and they should be stored as a dedicated data type in your database as well. The format only comes into play in the grid, when the data is converted for display. The data in the data source, which what actually gets should be type `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

If the data in your data source is not type `DateTime` then it should be, so you should first take steps to remedy that. You can then apply whatever formatting you want in the grid by setting the `.DefaultCellStyle.Format` property of the column.

Once you actually have data of the correct type, you can filter it properly, as per the documentation. Filtering actual `Dates` would look like this:

```vb
DataSource2Grid.Filter = String.Format("DataHoraPartida >= #{0:M/dd/yyyy}#' AND DataHoraPartida <= #{1:M/dd/yyyy}#", DateTimePicker1.Value, DateTimePicker2.Value)
```

`DateTime` literals are ALWAYS delimited with `#` characters and they are ALWAYS formatted using US date format, i.e. `M/dd/yyyy`. There's also no point specifying the `Date` property of the two values because the format already drops the time. I'd also recommend using string interpolation over `String.Format` in most cases if you're using VB 2015 (I think, or it may be 2017) or later:

```vb
DataSource2Grid.Filter = $"DataHoraPartida >= #{DateTimePicker1.Value:M/dd/yyyy}#' AND DataHoraPartida <= #{DateTimePicker2.Value:M/dd/yyyy}#"
```